# PL/SQL use VARRAY in IN CLAUSE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, varray

Is it possible to use VARRAY in IN CLAUSE of pl/sql?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can, provided that the VARRAY type is a global type (and not local to some PL/SQL code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE str_tab_type IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(200);

DECLARE
  l_str_tab str_tab_type;
  l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_str_tab := str_tab_type();
  l_str_tab.extend(2);
  l_str_tab(1) := 'TABLE';
  l_str_tab(2) := 'INDEX';

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count
  FROM all_objects
  WHERE object_type IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(l_str_tab));
END;
/
```