# Pl/SQL ORA-01722: invalid number in where clause

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql

I am using a variable to store numeric value range like the following:

```
:p_where := 7||','||8||','||9;

select * from <TABLE> where
col1 in (:p_where);
```

it will give the following error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

How to handle this issue?

Comment: There might be an answer for this question here [Sending an array of values to Oracle procedure to use in WHERE IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580245/sending-an-array-of-values-to-oracle-procedure-to-use-in-where-in-clause)

Answer (score 2):

If you do it the way you have shown us, you end up with this:

```
col1 in ('7,8,9');
```

instead of:

```
col11 in (7, 8, 9)
```

What you have to do is write a `PIPELINED` function that will tokenize a comma-delimited list of numbers and allow you to query that list and put them in `IN` list. I'm not sure this will work from Oracle Forms, please see the below example and try using it and give me some feedback:

```
CREATE TABLE test_pipe (
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  salary NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test_pipe VALUES (1, 'Smith', 5000);
INSERT INTO test_pipe VALUES (2, 'Brown', 8000);
INSERT INTO test_pipe VALUES (3, 'Bay', 10000);

COMMIT;

CREATE TYPE t_pipe_test_num_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func_num_pipe(p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN t_pipe_test_num_tab
  PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  FOR v_value IN (
          SELECT regexp_substr(p_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS token FROM dual
          CONNECT BY regexp_substr(p_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
        )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_value.token);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM test_pipe
WHERE id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(test_func_num_pipe('1,3')));
```

Output:

```
        ID NAME                     SALARY
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Smith                      5000 
         3 Bay                       10000
```