# Pro*C returning Not a number in the IN clause

Tags: c, oracle, proc

I am trying to run an SQL from my C code using Pro*c. This is my SQL

```
EXEC SQL select count(1) from MY_TABLE where id IN ( :format );
```

id is a NUMBER(10) and format is a char array containing value 1,2,3,4,5

This is returning error with "Not a Number"
However if the format array is just a single number, its running fine.
Please let me know if someone find the error.

Thx!

Comment: IN clause dont support bind variable this way. With Pro*C you may have form a query string with hard coded values or try [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:139812348065)

Comment: think about adding a list of arguments for the IN operator. No need to hard code it in the SQL, just add (:form1, :form2, ...)

Comment: @OracleUser: Plz add it as a comment so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` clause accept bind variables only as `(:1,:2,:3)` , so you have yo know the number of bind variables before hand. Which is not likely.

Simplest way is to form a *dynamic* query string with hard coded values in Pro*C.

There are alternative solutions from [AsKTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:139812348065) and [My SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695220/oracle-dynamic-query-with-in-clause-using-cursor/21695311#21695311)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        EXEC SQL select count(1) from MY_TABLE where id IN ( :format[i] );
    }
```

I am telling to use above code as it is too lousy, just explaining how arrays works in Pro*C. You have to give the index of the array.

Edit: I learned a new thing for this problem:- We can also use

```
    EXEC SQL FOR 5
        SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id IN (:format);

   EXEC SQL SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id IN 
             (:format[0],:format[1],:format[2],:format[3],:format[4])
```