# Dynamic cursor Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I want to create a dynamic cursor, but my code does not bring me the correct data. What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
 VAR1 VARCHAR2(500);
 CURSOR CUR1 IS
  SELECT T.COL1 FROM TABLE1 T WHERE T.COL1 IN (VAR1);

 BEGIN
  VAR1 := q'['V1','V2']';
  FOR REG IN CUR1 LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REG.COL1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Because IN string will be like _IN ''V1','V2''_ ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, IN clause doesn't support bind variables.. It supports for only value,in the way you used.. You need to specify it like `IN (var1, var2)`;

Without knowing you , you have used bind variables. One workaround is use `REFCURSOR` By forming a query string dynamically.

```
DECLARE
 VAR1 VARCHAR2(500);
 CUR1 SYs_REFCURSOR;
 QUERY_STRING VARCHAR2(2000) := 'SELECT T.COL1 FROM TABLE1 T WHERE T.COL1 IN';

 MYREC IS RECORD 
 (
   COL1 VARCHAR(1000);
 );

 myrecord MYREC;

 BEGIN
  VAR1 := q'['V1','V2']';
  QUERY_STRING:= QUERY_STRING||'('||VAR1||')';

  OPEN CUR1 FOR QUERy_STRING;

    LOOP
      FETCH CUR1 INTO myrecord;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myrecord.COL1);
      EXIT WHEN v_my_ref_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        ..
      -- your processing
    END LOOP;

  CLOSE CUR1;

END;
```

[One of my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695220/oracle-dynamic-query-with-in-clause-using-cursor/21695311#21695311) also has other way using collections, for bigger IN clause list.

Answer (score 1):

--I USED A TABLE IN OUR DB ORACLE 11G R2
--there are some syntax issues above that I corrected
--I moved the QUERY_STRING after the BEGIN and added output

```
DECLARE
 VAR1 VARCHAR2(500);
 CUR1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
 QUERY_STRING VARCHAR2(2000);

 TYPE MYREC IS RECORD 
 (
   WO_NBR VARCHAR(1000)
 );

 myrecord MYREC;

BEGIN
  VAR1 := q'['45466','45432']';
  QUERY_STRING := 'SELECT T.WO_NBR FROM WO_SCHED T WHERE T.WO_NBR IN  ('||VAR1||')';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(QUERY_STRING);

  OPEN CUR1 FOR QUERY_STRING;

    LOOP
      FETCH CUR1 INTO myrecord;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myrecord.WO_NBR);
      EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;

      -- your processing
    END LOOP;

  CLOSE CUR1;

END;
```