# How do I pass a database link as a variable in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, procedure, dblink

I have a form on a table. Entries in the form will define the link to use for a query. To make it work, I need to create a query that will select against the table and thereby generate the link to use. This is not the SQL I will be using, but the principle is the same. I have tried all manner of bars and quotes but I can't get oracle to compile the procedure and use the string in the table to action the query over the link. Can you help?

```
--Insert the name of a db_link here, in this case
--All that the table contains is "DEV01"

create table LINK_NAME
(LINK_NAME VARCHAR2(20));

--Now create a procedure to test selecting from the link
--Just using the string in the table to get its name:

create or replace procedure TEST_LINK is
v_link_name varchar2(10);
v_blah varchar2(10);
v_link varchar2(10);

--This passes the string "DEV01" into variable v_link:
cursor c1 is select link_name into v_link from link_name;

--This works, directly referencing the link name:
--cursor c2 is select name into v_blah from v$database@DEV01;

--This doesn't work, when I reference the link using the variable I've passed.
cursor c2 is select name into v_blah from v$database@||v_link;
--How can I get oracle to accept the variable to define the name of the link?

begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into v_link;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
end loop;

open c2;
loop
fetch c2 into v_blah;
EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
end loop;
--This just lets you check the database is doing the right thing:
select distinct link_name into v_link_name from pdu.link_name;
dbms_output.put_line(v_link_name||' and '||v_blah);
end ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046482/dynamic-cursor-oracle

Comment: I have examined query strings, however the part of the query that uses the link in my query that I'm trying to get working is many, many lines with many sub-queries... I've also examined how the variable is referenced in the link above and in replicating it, I get:    cursor c2 is select name into v_blah from v$database@'('||v_link||')'; which fails to compile when mapped to the above sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Using cursor to get one row is... Just try to avoid.

```
 create or replace procedure TEST_LINK 
 is
   v_blah      varchar2(10);
   v_link      varchar2(10);
 begin

 select link_name
 into   v_link
 from   link_name;

 execute immediate 'select count(1) from v$database@'||v_link
 into  v_blah;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_link||' and '||v_blah);
 end test_link;
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind using `execute immediate 'select count(1) from v$database@'||v_link` instead of  just `select count(1) from v$database@'||v_link`? Is the latter invalid SQL?